# Quorum/DApp Running in Secure Enclaves Such as Google Asylo

Tags: quorum

To secure the geth nodes and the keystores, can we run constellation and geth nodes within secure enclaves such as Google Asylo?

Or perhaps the DApp or Smart Contract could run in the secure enclaves.

How can this be achieved?

Nathan Aw

Comment: as far as I know, Asylo is a more secure version of docker. if so you can run your nodes on it and export the API through the enclaves or still run your whole Dapp in one enclave and export it after. Please tell me if I am wrong here.

Comment: i think you are absolutely right